# I need suggestion to split word and special characters in string

Tags: java, arrays, json

My String is as below

```
String responseBody = ["{\"event\":{\"commonEventHeader\":{\"sourceId\":\"\",\"startEpochMicrosec\":\"1590633627120000\",\"eventId\":\"135.16.61.40-Fault_bgp_neighbor_adjacency_down-192.20.126.67\",\"internalHeaderFields\"}"]
```

I want to split this string by  `event\"`:

I am trying below :

```
String[] json = responseBody.split("event\":");
```

This is not able to split , I am not getting any error too . Please suggest .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused as to why you wouldn't try to parse the JSON since it looks like you know it is JSON. But in the spirit of answering the actual question, I think it's because the string you are trying to split actually contains the `\` character, and therefore you should use:

```java
String[] json = responseBody.split("event\\\\\":");
```

Why so many `\`? Well the actual regex is `event\\":` but in Java, escape each `\` and the `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Built-in String method `split("regex")`.

Example:

```
 String s = "This is a String";

 //Split String

 String[] arr = s.split(" ");
```

Comment: I tried to do      String[] json = responseBody.split("event\\\\"); .............I am able to split with event\ ....but I want to split by event\":